# How do you create a reference to an object from its name as a string?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, dom-events

`window[objref]` does not work
`self[objref]` does not work either

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/Sebcn/).

Here is the code:

```
var bob = {
    n: {},
    y: {
        somekey: 12,
        oo: 'yah',
        pop: {
            t: 36
        }
    },
    m: function() {},
    l: 'hi'
};


function membersOf(s) {

    //var o = window[s]; // returns false false
    // var o = self[s]; // returns false false
    var o = s; // returns ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"] ["somekey", "oo", "pop"]

    var ret_array = [];
    for (var p in o) {
        if (o[p] != o.constructor.prototype[p]) {
            ret_array.push(p);
        }
    }
    if (ret_array.length === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return ret_array;
    }
}

var ref = 'bob.y';
var byname = membersOf(ref);
var byval = membersOf(bob.y);
console.log(byname, byval);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `var byval = membersOf(eval(ref));` ?

Comment: `byval` poses no problem as it would return correct result if `var o = s;` is uncommented; it is `byref` I am trying to get.

Comment: I tripped over my foolish naming scheme, and didn't get the point of your suggestion first - sorry ;) But it works if the ref is `eval`ed. I don't understand the why though.

Comment: The reason it works is without using eval you're looking at a string (no matter if it's a string constant such as 'bob.y' or if it's a string variable that's been assigned, it's still a string). The eval() function evaluates a string as if it were javascript -- it's intended for exactly the kind of thing you're doing with it.